# How to use lookup inside map for all elements in an array in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have two collections

Collection 1 is "individual"

```
{
 "id":string
 "name":string
 "DOB":date
 "occupation":string
}
```

collection 2 is "connectionsWith"

```
{
"individualId":string
"type":"friends":string
"connectionIds":[]
}
```

the aggregation query used is

```
db.individual.aggregate([
{
    "$match":{
        "_id":"bbin.ens3pvjeej0vg1bn3tcjr"
    }
},
{
    "$lookup":
   {
     "from": "connectionsWith",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "individualId",
     "as": "connections",

   }
},
{
    "$project":
    {
        "_id":1,
        "name":1,
        "connections":1
    }
}
])
```

Here the output is giving me connections in the array of Ids and now I want to display the name the connections instead of ids. Use of map would be the solution I guess but it is not allowing me to use lookup for names inside map. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Have been scratching on this from hours

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to replace the existing root with the joined object. For this you do not need to do a `$lookup` inside of a `$map`. Instead, you should use the `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` stages.

Since `$lookup` will inject a new `connections` array, what you want is to get a top level array of objects, each with one of those looked up connections. This is what `$unwind` does.

After that, the initial root can be replaced in each case with the connection itself.

Although I have only partially tested it, your full solution might look something along these lines. Check out the final two aggregate stages below:

```
db.individual.aggregate([
{
    "$match":{
        "_id":"bbin.ens3pvjeej0vg1bn3tcjr"
    }
},
{
    "$lookup":
   {
     "from": "connectionsWith",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "individualId",
     "as": "connections",

   }
},
{
    "$project":
    {
        "_id":1,
        "name":1,
        "connections":1
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$connections"
},
{
    "$replaceRoot":
    {
        "newRoot": "$connections"
    }
}
])
```